# Is there any way to write debug output to Android Studio in design mode?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

When the output in design mode is not as expected in Android Studio, is there anyway to debug this by for instance inserting log-writing code that will be visible in the Android Studio IDE?

Let's say you're coding a custom View which will render a triangle. The designer renders a blank view. You want to inspect the variables at a certain point in the onDraw-method. The only way I've found is to insert a `throw new RuntimeException("X is: " +x)`. This produces an exception which is visible in the designer, but it's not a good solution.

Is it possible to insert any smoother code which doesn't terminate the execution and still allows you to inspect the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of how to do this in design mode, but you could set up a quick test of the view to do this while running.

Android Studio provides a real-time **logcat** view for connected devices - just click the Android label at the bottom of the IDE.

You can use the logcat to monitor any output you specify using the Android [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) object's methods.

It might be a good idea to use a custom tag for your log entries and then filter the logcat to only display entries with that tag, for example:

```
Log.v( "SomeLabel", "X is: " +x );
```

If you filter the output to **SomeLabel** in this example, you will only see the entries you want.

Also, if your onDraw method runs in real-time, it might be a good idea to only log once per second (or at some desired interval), instead of every call.